# Assigning a version to a jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, manifest

Simple issue: I'd like to assign a new version\build number every time I issue a new jar file to my customers.

I understood that a manufest file is involved but I fail to get the version whatever I have tried so far.

My jar project has two packages under a common "com" package: "main" and "loginRequest".

My main class ("Main") is under the "main" package.

My manifest file is :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: main.Main
Specification-Version: 1.1
```

I tried to build the jar using eclipse (excluding the src files), including the manifest.

I also tried the following:

```
jar -cvfm v11_4_WebExClientEE.jar ..\..\v11_4_WebExClientEE.mf main\Main.class
```

which retruned me

```
"added manifest

 adding: main/Main.class(in = 1206) (out= 677)(deflated 43%)"
```

and then:

```
java -jar v11_4_WebExClientEE.jar
```

which returned me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: main/Main (wrong name: com/main/Main)
```

etc.

In my main class ctor I added:

```
    Package p = this.getClass().getPackage();

    System.out.println("v11_4_WebExClientEE spec Version : " + p.getSpecificationVersion());
```

Can you please advise?

Thanks!

Comment: what's the package in which your main class exists? Are you sure you need manifest version and not something like v11_4_WebExClientEE-<version>.jar?

Comment: The main class, which is called Main, is under the package "main". Do you suggest I should add the version number to the jar name?

Comment: Yes. In that way you could maintain various version in centralised repository and let your client pick up from that repository via maven/ivy.

Comment: Right, but this way he would have to update it's project classpath each time I change the the jar name with the new jar. I would have prefer to avoid it if possible...

Comment: So if you have two jars and you want to check latest one are you going to traverse through jar's manifest? You could use wildcard if it's just classpath.

Answer (score 2):

The clue to what you did wrong is in the exception message:

> ... NoClassDefFoundError: main/Main (wrong name: com/main/Main)

The JVM has found the entry for your entry point class (according to your "Main-Class" attribute) but the classloader has thrown an exception that the JAR entry pathname doesn't match the full package name for your class.  (The classloader was expecting "main/Main" but the actual package name was "/com/main/Main" ... according to the class file contents.)

> Following the details I gave, should it be com/main/*.class ?

Yes.  That is what you should put on the `jar` command line to add the classes with the correct JAR paths.  (Or at least something like that.  The key thing is that the argument(s) should correspond to the full entry path that you require for the JAR file; i.e. the fully qualified classname(s).)

> and what should I put instead of java/util/ and java.util ?

The Name attribute probably should not be there at all.  A "Name" attribute introduces a manifest section for an entry in the JAR file.

The "Implementation-Title" attribute is purely descriptive.  You can put whatever you want there.

Before you go any further, I **strongly recommend** that you read the [JAR file specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR_Manifest) **carefully**.  Pay attention to what the spec says about the manifest syntax, and what the manifest attributes mean.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I updated the jar command as you offered ang received the following: com\main\*.class : no such file or directory
added manifest.

main has backslash after it(!) althogh you might not see it the comment... 

The directory structure is c:\Users\<user>\Documents\eclipse\<proj name>\bin\com\main\

Answer (score 0):

We first create a text file named **Manifest.txt** with the following contents:

```
Name: com/main/
Specification-Title: Main Common Class
Specification-Version: 1.2
Specification-Vendor: Example Tech, Inc.
Implementation-Title: com.main 
Implementation-Version: build57
Implementation-Vendor: Example Tech, Inc.
```

We then create a **JAR** file named **MyJar_1.2.jar** by entering the following command:

```
jar cfm MyJar_1.2.jar Manifest.txt MyPackage/*.class
```

Comment: I am sorry, I did not completely understand your advise. Can you give me an example please? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I saw this example on web and tried it. I think that my problem was that I didn't knew exactly which value to put instead of MyPackage. Following the details I gave, should it be com/main/*.class ? and what should I put instead of java/util/ and java.util ? Does it matter?

Comment: You can remove Implementation-Title:,if you want to use it when implemeting other package and yes com/main/*.class should work